# SMB issue- Access denied

Tags: windows, file-permissions, server-message-block

i have a windows server 2012 R2 for file sharing purpose, clients are using win 7 64 bit. network drives are mapped on profile.

Issue: some user drives disconnect suddenly with the message of Access denied.
although all the users assign rights on server are ok.

how i resolve: i disconnect all the drive and remapped, or i logoff the profile and re-login, so issue get resolved.
but i makes the users frustrated and cause hindrance in their work

please help .?

Answer (score 2):

It can be a problem with SMB 2 and security patches. Try to disable the firewall on both client and server or even disable SMB2 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3035936/access-denied-error-message-when-you-access-an-smb-file-share-in-windo

To disable SMB2 you can use this article https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/57499.htm